# Query mapping to database in NLIDB systems

Tags: nlp

In NLIDB, how should I map a word in my query to the database attribute? eg. there is emp_name attribute in employee table in my database and my query is 'Give name of all employees'?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take the time to write a question with what you have tried, what doesn't work and how you would like to improve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NLIDB is a branch of NLP that is active for the last couple of decades. There are many techniques in use today to solve common NLP tasks. So there would be an answer for each technique...

The mapping of a NL query to a SQL query is the domain of Semantic Parsing. The technique I favor is based on logic programming and Feature based grammars [FCFG](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnlp%5D%20fcfg).

NTLK.org is a research site offering numerous tools and techniques. In their book [available online](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html) look for the string "sql0.fcfg". The example shows how to map the NL phrase structure query "What cities are located in China" into an SQL query "SELECT City FROM city_table WHERE Country="china" via the feature "SEM" or semantics of the FCFG.